# Set exact value for midpoint of unclassed color symbology in ArcGIS Pro

Tags: arcgis-pro, symbology

When using "Unclassed Colors" as the primary symbology of a raster layer in ArcGIS Pro, is it possible to set an exact value for the midpoint? It appears as if you can only specify the min and max values:

[image]

I want to achieve a divergent color ramp that centers on 0. The best I can do is play around with the colors of the actual color ramp, but this is not exactly scientific and does not achieve the precision I am after.

[image]

[image]

And I do not with to use a classifed symbology, which I realize does allow you to specify specific breakpoints.

Answer (score 0):

From what I've found, editing the color ramp is the easiest way to adjust midpoint values. For a slightly more precise midpoint, you can calculate the position percent of your desired midpoint for the color ramp editor.

|Min| / (|Min| + |Max|) = position %

If your color ramp is inverted, invert the percent value as well (for example 18% would change to 82%).